# What does the woman say in the opening to Al B. Sure's, "Ooh This Love Is So"

Tags: lyrics

In the opening sequence of Al B. Sure's, "Ooh This Love Is So", from the album "In Effect Mode", a woman purrs a line or two in what sounds like French to me.  I've wondered for decades what she said.  Can you tell me?

Answer (score 0):

She is saying, in French,

> Oooh, cet amour est tellement // Que je ne te laisserai pas partir

Which is a translation of the song's first English lyrics:

> Oooh, this love is so ... // that I won't let you go